# Div has image and text elements inside of it, I want the text to be centered absolutely in the center over the image

Tags: html, css

I've applied the code in the snippet below. My goal is to position the `<p>` element with class summoner-level over the image and have it centered horizontally and vertically. Sadly I have no clue how and the code I've found on google doesn't really work for some reason. I assume this is not too hard but I'm not too familiar with absolute positioning.

```css
    *, *:after, *:before {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        text-decoration: none;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    html {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    body {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        line-height: 1.8rem;
        color: #333333;
    }
.summoner-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.summoner-information {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.summoner-icon-container {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}
.summoner-level {
    position: absolute;
}
.summoner-icon {
    max-width: 75px;
}
```

```html
        <div class='summoner-container'>
            <div class='summoner-information'>
                <div class="summoner-icon-container">
                    <p class='summoner-level'>150</p>
                    <img class='summoner-icon' v-if='summonerInfo' src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.13.1/img/profileicon/1250.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flex alignment/justification since your container is already set to `display: flex`

```
.summoner-icon-container {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have come right way!

You just add this!

```
.summoner-level {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

will be dynamically center

```css
*, *:after, *:before {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        text-decoration: none;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    html {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    body {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        line-height: 1.8rem;
        color: #333333;
    }
.summoner-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.summoner-information {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.summoner-icon-container {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
}
.summoner-level {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.summoner-icon {
    max-width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class='summoner-container'>
            <div class='summoner-information'>
                <div class="summoner-icon-container">
                    <p class='summoner-level'>150</p>
                    <img class='summoner-icon' v-if='summonerInfo' src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/9.13.1/img/profileicon/1250.png" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
.summoner-icon-container {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```